# Cronjob does not work anymore after copying it

Tags: raspbian, cron

I recently reinstalled my Raspberry Pi after I changed the microSD-Card. I copied all my `cron` jobs manually (in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`) and after I imported them with root on my new installation, they don't work anymore.

Any idea why?

This is the output of `sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

```
-rw------- 1 pi   crontab 11816 Apr 19 09:24 pi
-rw------- 1 root crontab  1169 Apr 19 09:19 root
```

Edit:

I solved it. There were two major issues. First, I needed to set the owner-ship of my file to the Pi-User:

```
chown <username> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>
```

And second, the time was wrong. Therefore the `cron` started an hour later than it was supposed to start.

Comment: Please run `sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs`, and add the output to your question.

Comment: Alright, I've put the output in my question.

Comment: It would have been better to answer your question in the answer, not in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way that keeps security ownership correct between machines is to list the details out to a file and just paste that back on the new machine using the correct user.

```
crontab -l > details.txt
```

will create the full contents (comments inc) for that users cron jobs in the file.

You can then just paste that back within an editor or pipe it back with:

```
cat details.txt | crontab
```